# Tight Flight connection : Have I made a mistake?

Tags: transit, layovers, short-connections, ams

I'm traveling to the US from India, specifically the Bangalore - Schiphol - Seattle route. The first leg is operated by KLM and the second leg is operated by KLM partner Delta. I just have a 1 hr 25 min flight connection time. Will be arriving at 8:25 AM in Schiphol and next departure is at 9:50 AM. Since this is an international flight and I have to pass through screening again, I'm wondering if I have made a mistake booking this flight. Both flights are on the same ticket/booking.

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket/booking? If they are it shouldn't be a problem. If they aren't and you have checked luggage, it's basically impossible.

Comment: Note: security screening is relatively fast: it is not the immigration control (which sometime it is very slow also in AMS). Consider also that intercontinental flights have often pessimistic arrival time, OTOH traffic restriction in Pakistan, Iran, Iraq had negative effect unaccounted on timetable publications.

Answer (score 2):

Transfers at Schipol airport is very simple, and I have done it many times.

KLM advise that 50 mins is ample for a transfer on an intercontinental flight.

https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/at_the_airport/connections/index.htm

The airport website

https://www.schiphol.nl/en/transfers/

Has a tool to work out your transfer times.

As you say you are on one ticket, your luggage should be checked all the way though. But as per the comments on the question you cannot guarantee that your first flight will arrive on time.  However as you are on one booking if you don’t make the connection KLM Delta will make rearrangements if required.

In short.   You should be fine